# A work by smb, a work of smb or smb's work—which of them is better?

Tags: prepositions, possessives

Example:

> 1) *War and peace* is a novel by Leo Tolstoy.
>   2) *War and peace* is a novel of Leo Tolstoy.
>   3) *War and peace* is Leo Tolstoy's novel.

An English language test which I have passed told me that only the first variant is correct. I doubt a little about that. Which variant is indeed correct, or the best of the three variants mentioned above?

Comment: As a stand-alone sentence, I would agree that the first is the best. But as you say, they are all correct, though, normally, we would probably say, "War and Peace is a novel of Leo Tolstoy's" (adding the possessive apostrophe -s). And the third one is less common, I feel.

Comment: Had your tests been testing for prepositions? Or sentence construction?

Comment: Teacher KSHuang, it was a complex test about almost all English grammar. From articles and prepositions to conditional sentences. Very good test, although some questions are ambiguous.

Comment: I see. I ask because if you are trying to decide on sentence construction for meaning, I would suggest the first one. But if you're just asking about grammatical correctness, then, yes, they're all correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these sentences are grammatically correct but the first is the only one that conveys the correct meaning.

> 2) *War and peace* is a novel of Leo Tolstoy.

The problem with this is that we use the preposition **of** to refer to the subject matter of a book: "..a novel of adventure, intrigue and romance" or "... a novel of Pakistan". See [this](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=%22a%20novel%20of%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=DanHWJf8AcSsa43whegO) for more examples.

> 3) *War and peace* is Leo Tolstoy's novel.

This would only work if Tolstoy had written just one novel. You could instead say:

> *War and peace* is one of Leo Tolstoy's novels.
>   *War and peace* is Leo Tolstoy's novel about the French invasion of Russia.

Comment: Wouldn't number two be better written as: War and **P** eace is a novel of Leo Tolstoy **'s**?

Comment: @Davo: yes, that would work.